# Auto Complete with locations like the one from Google Maps

Tags: android

I im building a home project and i want to create a auto complete text view used to suggest addresses.To make the story short i world want it to be just like the one in google maps.I am familiar with java and webservices but i realy dont know where to start.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about Place Autocomplete API? https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete